# How can I install the VSCode help files in an offline network

Tags: visual-studio-code, documentation, offline

VSCode help files appear to be online links.  I do not have access to the internet on my systems.  How can I get the help files for offline use?

Answer (score 0):

As it currently stands, if you have no internet access there, you would need to clone the [microsoft/vscode-docs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs) repository on Microsoft's GitHub, and view them locally via some sort of markdown viewer.

This is far from ideal, given that there are images and videos hosted elsewhere, as well as other resources they're likely to have. Given the constraints you mentioned, this is all I can see that will help you out.